# Create a git branch from selected commits on another branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-rebase

I created a "feature" branch off master and worked for a long while.  I then fetched the latest master branch commits and rebased my "feature" branch commits on top of it.  Then I merged "feature" into master.  However, I forgot about the merge and continued committing into the "feature" branch.  I want those commits in a new branch now, so I would now like to create another branch, "feature_2", that is based on the commits on the "feature" branch since the last merge into master.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that:

- `feature` already references commits since last merge into `master`
- branches are just pointers

```
x--x--x (master)
       \
        y--y--y (feature)
```

, you can simply:

- `git checkout feature`
- `git checkout -b feature2`
- `git branch -f feature master`
  (provided no commits were made on `master` since the `feature` merge)

```
x--x--x (master, feature)
       \
        y--y--y (feature2)
```

All the commits from master are no longer referenced by `feature` (which is reset to where `master` is), but are now accessible through `feature2` (which is where `feature` is before being reset to `master`)

---

The OP [Chip Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372599/chip-castle) adds:

> I have 3 other team members who have had their branches merged into master since then, so I don't want to merge the same commits I have already merged.
>   I was hoping to give a SHA range only for the commits I need from feature to a new branch. Is there any way to do that or a better way?

So the situation is:

```
x--x--x--y'--y' (master, updated after a fetch from other repo)
       \
        y'--y'--y--y (feature, with y' being already merged, 
                      and y being the commits I need)
```

Then you can simply rebase feature on top of master: identical commits will be ignored.

Comment: I have 3 other team members who have had their branches merged into master since then, so I don't want to merge the same commits I have already merged.  I was hoping to give a SHA range only for the commits I need from feature to a new branch.  Is there any way to do that or a better way?

Comment: @Chip: I have updated my answer, but don't hesitate to leave a comment here if I have misunderstood your exact situation, and edit your question with a diagram illustrating your current repo state if necessary.